# Accessing value of array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

We know that we can dynamically create variables using pointers as for example:

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

We can access its value using `*` as

```
cout << *p;
```

But this is not the case of the array, consider the below code:

```
int size_array = 5;
int * p = new int[size_array];
```

if we need to access the value of the first element, we do the following:

```
cout << p[0];
```

but why we can't do the same as for a dynamic variable like above?, i.e. using `*`:

```
cout << *p[0];
```

Comment: You can.  `*p` or `p[0]`.  `*(p+1)` or `p[1]`.  Et cetera.

Comment: `p[index]` is the same as `*(p+index)`, so `*p` works just fine whether you use `new int` or `new int[size_array]`, just note that in the second case it only accesses the 1st element in the array, unless `p` is updated to point at another element. Which you shouldn't do, use a separate pointer for that, if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p[0]` is syntax sugar (for arrays) for:

```
*(p + 0)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
*p
```

---

`*p[0]` does not work because it is equivalent to:

```
**p
```

In other words, de-referencing the pointer/array twice.