# Why strings can be used like this

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

C++ code

```
string *stra;
string strb = "ABC";
stra = &strb;
std::cout <<  stra[0][1] << std::endl;
std::cout << *stra << " " << stra[0]<< std::endl;
```

why use `stra[0]` is print same at `*stra` or why I can use like that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing value of array using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185973/accessing-value-of-array-using-pointers)

Comment: `A[B]` is defined as `*((A)+(B))`. ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.2.1 Subscripting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ 14 Standard (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
> a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
> “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped
> enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T”
> shall be a completely-defined object type.64 The expression E1[E2] is
> identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for
> details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ], except
> that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is
> an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

So the expression `stra[0]` is evaluated like `*( stra + 0 )` that is the same as `*stra`.

Pay attention to that as the operation `+` is commutative then this expression `*( stra + 0 )` is the same as `*( 0 + stra )`. That means that you may even write `0[stra]` instead of `stra[0]`.

Here is a demonstrative program that instead of objects of the type `std::string` uses string litarals.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Heelo"[0] << ' ' << *"Hello" << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
H H
```

String literals in C++ are represented by constant character arrays. For example the string literal `"Hello"` is stored like an unnamed character array

```
const char unnamed_string_literal[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

Used in expressions with the dereferencing operator * or the subscript operator [] they are converted to pointers to their first elements of the type `const char *`. Thus this statement

```
    std::cout << "Heelo"[0] << ' ' << *"Hello" << '\n';
```

outputs the first character of the string literal `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

By definition (as also said @MikeCAT) operation `A[B]` (for plain arrays) is defined as `*(A + B)`.

This is operation of array indexing - obtaining value of array's element. In C/C++ plain arrays are often represented just by a pointer. This operation allows reading value of array A at B'th index.

Just dereferencing operator `*A` is same as saying `*(A + 0)`. Hence `A[0]` does same as just `*A`.

Comment: "array name can decay to pointer" . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer